# How do I tokenise a word given tokens that are subsumed incompletely in the word?

Tags: regex, perl, token

I understand how to use regex in Perl in the following way:

```
$str =~ s/expression/replacement/g;
```

I understand that if any part of the expression is enclosed in parentheses, it can be used and captured in the replacement part, like this:

```
$str =~ s/(a)/($1)dosomething/;
```

But is there a way to capture the `($1)` above *outside* of the regex expression?

I have a full word which is a string of consonants, e.g. `bEdmA`, its vowelized version `baEodamaA` (where `a` and `o` are vowels), as well its split up form of two tokens, separated by space, `bEd maA`. I want to just pick up the vowelized form of the tokens from the full word, like so: `beEoda`, `maA`. I'm trying to capture the token within the full word expression, so I have:

```
$unvowelizedword = "bEdmA";
$tokens[0] = "bEd", $tokens[1] = "mA";
$vowelizedword = "baEodamA";

foreach $t(@tokens) {
    #find the token within the full word, and capture its vowels
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$vowelizedword = m/($t)/;
```

This is completely wrong for two reasons: the token `$t` is not present in exactly its own form, such as `bEd`, but something like `m/b.E.d/` would be more relevant. Also, how do I capture it in a variable *outside* the regular expression?

The real question is: how can I capture the vowelized sequences `baEoda` and `maA`, given the tokens `bEd`, `mA` from the full word `beEodamaA`?

---

### Edit

I realized from all the answers that I missed out two important details.

1. Vowels are *optional*. So if the tokens are : "Al" and "ywm", and the fully vowelized word is "Alyawmi", then the output tokens would be "Al" and "yawmi".
2. I only mentioned two vowels, but there are more, including symbols made up of two characters, like '~a'. The full list (although I don't think I need to mention it here) is:

   @vowels = ('a', 'i', 'u', 'o', '~', '~a', '~i', '~u', 'N', 'F', 'K', '~N', '~K');

Comment: This isn't English. This is a transliteration - those symbols represent vowels in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @tokens = ('bEd', 'mA');
my $vowelizedword = "beEodamaA";

my @regex = map { join('.?', split //) . '.?' } @tokens;

my $regex = join('|', @regex);
$regex = qr/($regex)/;

while (my ($matched) = $vowelizedword =~ $regex) {
    $vowelizedword =~ s{$regex}{};
    print "matched $matched\n";
}
```

Update as per your updated question (vowels are optional). It works from the end of the string so you'll have to gather the tokens into an array and print them in reverse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @tokens = ('bEd', 'mA', 'Al', 'ywm');
my $vowelizedword = "beEodamaA Alyawmi"; # Caveat: Without the space it won't work.

my @regex = map { join('.?', split //) . '.?$' } @tokens;

my $regex = join('|', @regex);
$regex = qr/($regex)/;

while (my ($matched) = $vowelizedword =~ $regex) {
        $vowelizedword =~ s{$regex}{};
            print "matched $matched\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks this looks neat and works fine - except for one thing - vowels are optional - I just edited the question.

Comment: Replace the '.?' regex with '(' . join('|', @vowels) . ')?' and you might get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `m//` operator in so-called "list context", as this:

`my @tokens = ($input =~ m/capturing_regex_here/modifiershere);`

Answer (score 0):

**ETA:** From what I understand now, what you were trying to say is that you want to match an optional vowel after each character of the tokens.

With this, you can tweak the `$vowels` variable to only contain the letters you seek. Optionally, you may also just use `.` to capture any character.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @tokens = ("bEd", "mA");
my $full = "baEodamA";

my $vowels = "[aeiouy]";
my @matches;
for my $rx (@tokens) {
    $rx =~ s/.\K/$vowels?/g;
    if ($full =~ /$rx/) {
        push @matches, $full =~ /$rx/g;
    }
}

print Dumper \@matches;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'baEoda',
          'mA'
        ];
```

Note that

```
... $full =~ /$rx/g;
```

does [not require capturing groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Matching-in-list-context) in the regex.

Comment: @briandfoy It's a very handy feature, and much more pleasing to the eye than the other options.

Comment: yes, that's right! vowels are optional. But how do i deal with the fact that vowels maybe more than a single character? I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is an easier way to do whatever you're trying to accomplish. The trick is not to make the regex generation code so tricky that you forget what it's actually doing.

I can only begin to guess at your task, but from your single example, it looks like you want to check that the two subtokens are in the larger token, ignoring certain characters. I'm going to guess that those sub tokens have to be in order and can't have anything else between them besides those vowel characters.

To match the tokens, I can use the `\G` anchor with the `/g` global flag in scalar context. This anchors the match to the character one after the end of the last match for the same scalar. This way allows me to have separate patterns for each sub token. This is much easier to manage since I only need to change the list of values in `@subtokens`.

Once you go through each of the pairs and find which ones match all the patterns, I can extract the original string from the pair.

```
use v5.14;

my $vowels    = '[ao]*';
my @subtokens = qw(bEd mA);

# prepare the subtoken regular expressions
my @patterns = map {
    my $s = join "$vowels", map quotemeta, (split( // ), '');
    qr/$s/;
    } @subtokens;

my @tokens = qw( baEodamA mAabaEod baEoda mAbaEoda );

my @grand_matches;
TOKEN: foreach my $token ( @tokens ) {
    say "-------\nMatching $token..........";
    my @matches;
    PATTERN: foreach my $pattern ( @patterns ) {
        say "Position is ", pos($token) // 0;

        # scalar context /g and \G
        next TOKEN unless $token =~ /\G($pattern)/g; 
        push @matches, $1;
        say "Matched with $pattern";
        }
    push @grand_matches, [ $token, \@matches ];
    }

# Now report the original   
foreach my $tuple ( @grand_matches ) {
    say "$tuple->[0] has both fragments: @{$tuple->[1]}";
    }
```

Now, here's the nice thing about this structure. I've probably guessed wrong about your task. If I have, it's easy to fix without changing the setup. Let's say that the subtokens don't have to be in order. That's an easy change to the pattern I created. I just get rid of the
`\G` anchor and the `/g` flag;

```
        next TOKEN unless $token =~ /($pattern)/;
```

Or, suppose that the tokens have to be in order, but other things may be between them. I can insert a `.*?` to match that stuff, effectively skipping over it:

```
        next TOKEN unless $token =~ /\G.*?($pattern)/g;
```

It would be much nicer if I could manage all of this from the `map` where I create the patterns, but the `/g` flag isn't a pattern flag. It has to go with the operator.

I find it much easier to manage changing requirements when I don't wrap everything in a single regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the tokens need to appear in order and without anything (other than a vowel) between them:

```
my @tokens = ( "bEd", "mA" );
my $vowelizedword = "baEodamaA";

my $vowels = '[ao]';
my (@vowelized_sequences) = $vowelizedword =~ ( '^' . join( '', map "(" . join( $vowels, split( //, $_ ) ) . "(?:$vowels)?)", @tokens ) . '\\z' );
print for @vowelized_sequences;
```