# Quotemeta in perl? How to solve error: "Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE"

Tags: regex, perl

The following is the code:

```
my $vowels = "[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]";
my @diactok;
for $rx (@tokens) {
    $rx =~ s/.\K/$vowels?/g;
    if ($diac =~ /($rx)/) {
        push @diactok, $diac =~ /$rx/g;
    }
}
```

From this previous question: [How do I tokenise a word given tokens that are subsumed incompletely in the word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502630/how-do-i-tokenise-a-word-given-tokens-that-are-subsumed-incompletely-in-the-word/)

It's fine except for this error (I did "use diagnostics"):

> Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
>           m/(A[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?l[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?* <-- HERE [aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?y[aiou~N FKPQRIJ]?n[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)/ at
>   tokenizeForCRFinput.pl line 47,  line 28 8670 (#3)
>       (F) You can't quantify a quantifier without intervening parentheses. So
>       things like ** or +* or ?* are illegal. The <-- HERE shows in the regular
>       expression about where the problem was discovered.
>
> ```
> Note that the minimal matching quantifiers, *?, +?, and
> ?? appear to be nested quantifiers, but aren't.  See perlre.
> ```
>
> Uncaught exception from user code:
>           Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(A[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?l [aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?* <-- HERE
>   [aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?y[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?n[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)/ at
>   tokenizeForCRFinput.pl line 47,  line 288670.  at
>   tokenizeForCRFinput.pl line 47

Line 47 is this one:

```
if ($diac =~ /($rx)/)
```

I tried quotemeta but that didn't work - maybe I'm using it wrong? Some of the strings captured in `$diac` do indeed have special characters like `'?'` and `'*'`.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
$rx =~ s/.\K/$vowels?/g;
```

Is the culprit, if you indeed have meta characters in `@tokens`. Try this:

```
$rx =~ s/(.)/ quotemeta($1) . "$vowels?" /eg;
```

Note that you cannot quotemeta the whole regex, since you have meta characters in `$vowels` that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is originally

```
(Al*yn)
```

You change it to

```
(A[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?l[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?*[aiou~NFKP...
```

Like the nessage says, `[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?*` is wrong. You didn't specify what you want, so it's hard to give you a fix.

Maybe you want

```
(A(?:[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)l(?:[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)*(?:[aiou~NFKP...
```

If so, just use

```
$rx =~ s/.\K/(?:$vowels?)/g;
```

Maybe you want

```
(A(?:[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)(?:l[aiou~NFKPQRIJ]?)*(?:[aiou~NFKP...
```

If so, you'd need a much better regex parser than `/./`.